# How to use Python ThreadPool for a nested algorithm?

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I would like to use Python's `ThreadPool` from `multiprocessing.pool` to speed up my code.

I first have function A that runs a parallelizable subroutine for 100+ times.

I then have function B that runs function A 10 times (reach run also does not depend on other runs).

Finally, I have function C that runs function B 5 times (also parallelizable).

Assuming that my CPU has 32 cores, do I just initialise `ThreadPool(32)` in function A to parallelize the subroutine with most iterations? Or can I simply create 10 threads for function B and 5 threads for function C as well and Python will handle the many created threads for me?

Comment: Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) only allows a single thread to run at a time. Its executor may swap threads between op codes and C functions (especially ones that block) may also release the GIL and run in parallel. If your tasks are CPU bound they likely will not benefit from multithreading.

Comment: How do I check if they are CPU bound? Try threadpool and check for speed up?

Comment: Primarily its a question of whether they make blocking system calls or sleep. For instance, the requests library makes blocking network calls and is not cpu bound. `numpy` and `pandas` may release the gil and run in parallel, but that's kind of hit and miss. It depends on your data  and the functions used - in that case you need to experiment.